# The file with extension .txt doesn't work in Visual Studio Text Editor

Tags: python

When I create a text file in Vscode with an extension .txt, it doesn't work. You will understand better with this image.

[image]

You can see in this image, no icon is displayed. When I give extension of any file like .py the icon is diplayed but doesn't work for .txt?

And, when I try to run this python code to read this text file:

```
f = open("sample.txt","r")
data = f.read()
print(data)
f.close()
```

It shows this error:

```
No such file or directory
```

I have put the file in the same folder still not working
and the same case is with the mp3 files!

Comment: The icon for txt files is the default icon. Re. "file not found": Are you running that script in the same directory that contains the file you're trying to read? What does `import os; print(os.getcwd())` print?

Comment: Both files show as "unsaved" in the editor. Are you certain that you are running the code you expect?

Comment: Yes! I see it! I wasn't saving the. It works now ! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: May God Bless you all !!!!! Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Nothing wrong with the icon, .txt or .mp3 have that icon it's okay.
2. Problem is with your current working directory as you have sample.txt file in Day9 folder so you should try this `f = open('Day9/sample.txt')`.

Comment: I found the solution. When I put the file outside the folder "Day9" it works. But another problem is when I write some text in this text file using Vscode and run the code to read the file, it prints nothing but when I write some text using notepad out from Vscode and save the file it works. Why does not the text get saved when I write in Vscode?

Comment: Both files in your screenshot are not saved, you can see that small circle on the tab. So I think you are running code without even saving the files. @JonSG also mentioned that above.

Comment: Yeah I see it now! I was not saving the files! Thanks a Lot